# Cauchy Counter Example

Tags: real-analysis

What is an example of a Cauchy sequence X_n and a bounded sequence Y_n such that their product is not Cauchy?

I've tried Y_n= (-1)^n but I'm not sure what to multiply is by so it's not Cauchy.

Comment: Is the constant sequence $X_n=1$ Cauchy?

Comment: Oh, yes it is. Thanks